# I am getting an Error with LoadTexBPM using OPENGL

Tags: c, bmp

I am trying to add a texture to my surface but im getting the error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:"_LoadTexBMP", referenced from: _main in ex6.o
```

and it also says

```
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [learn] Error 1.
```

My main code is

```
glutInit(&argc,argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
glutCreateWindow("Learning");
glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
//glutIdleFunc(idle);
glutSpecialFunc(special);
glutKeyboardFunc(key);
glutIdleFunc(idle);
texture[0] = LoadTexBMP("./wall.bmp");
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
```

Comment: This error is not related to OpenGL.

Comment: would it be from another function?

Comment: I don't know where this function comes from, but it has nothing to do with OpenGL. ([OpenGL specification - Khronos OpenGL registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_gl.php) )

Comment: This is an error from the linker. It can't find function `LoadTexBMP`. You probably need to supply a library with this function, i.e. add an option such as `/usr/local/lib/libwherever.a` to the link command.